# Overridden function calling base function

Tags: python, django

I've been working on learning Django from MDN Web Docs. In part 6, this comes up:

"We might also override get_context_data() in order to pass additional context variables to the template (e.g. the list of books is passed by default). The fragment below shows how to add a variable named "some_data" to the context (it would then be available as a template variable)."

```
class BookListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Book

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get the context
        context = super(BookListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # Create any data and add it to the context
        context['some_data'] = 'This is just some data'

        return context
```

I am confused how the overridden "get_context_data" is calling itself in essence, but without recursion. Does super only call the overridden function after it is fully declared, or is this behavior not exclusive to super.
Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Generic_views

Comment: The overridden `get_context_data` method is not calling itself, but calling the `get_context_data` method of a parent class in the [MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) that defines the method.